# How to sort by two fields one of which is enum?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-stream

I need to sort a List in alphabetical order by name and then to sort it one more time by type and put on the top of the list elements with specific type. This is what I have done so far, but it didn't work as expected and it returns the list sorted only by name.

```
  public List<PRDto> present(
      List<ParticipantReference> participants) {
    return participants.stream()
        .map(MAPPER::toDto)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparing(PRDto::getName)
            .thenComparing(PRDto::getParticipantType, (type1, type2) -> {
              if (type1.equals(type2)) {
                return 0;
              }
              if (type2.equals(ParticipantType.S.getDescription())) {
                return 1;
              }
              if (type1.equals(ParticipantType.S.getDescription())) {
                return -1;
              }
              return type1.compareTo(type2);
            }))
        .collect(toList());
    }
```

This is my enum:

```
@Getter
public enum ParticipantType {
  F("F"),
  D_F("D+F"),
  S("S");

  private final String description;

  ParticipantType(String description) {
    this.description = description;
  }
}
```

Comment: If the names are unique then sorting by name first won't even use the enums. Can you provide some sample input and what you'd expect?

Comment: I expect a list on the top of which are the elements with type "S" and after that all other elements sorted alphabetically

Comment: Now the values are only sorted alphabetically, how can I do the second sorting and put values with specific type on the top?

Comment: In that case you need to sort by type _first_ and then by name. Btw, I'd not pass a custom compare lambda but just a mapping of `ParticipantType` to order, e.g. `S -> 0, all others -> 1` (assuming that's what you want) and then let `Comparator` sort by that order. That's easier to do and less error prone.

Comment: But if i will sort by type first, after I will sort the list by name the elements will be moved from the top and sorted by alphabetical order, is it right?

Comment: No, sorting doesn't work like you know it from Excel and the like. Since you're passing _one_ composite comparator it will put the `S` elements at the top. I'll add an example to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To preserve readability I would not leave the comparison in the stream pipeline but extract it in a comparator

```
 public List<PRDto> present(List<ParticipantReference> participants) {

    Comparator<PRDto> byType = Comparator.comparing(o -> !o.getType().equals(ParticipantType.S));

    Comparator<PRDto> byName = Comparator.comparing(PRDto::getName);

    return participants.stream().sorted(byType.thenComparing(byName)).collect(toList());
}
```

My answer had unnecessary redundant logic, which @Holger thankfully pointed out to me. This could also be inlined as Holger mentions it in the comments to:

```
return participants.stream().sorted(
                   Comparator.comparing((PRDto o) -> !o.getType().equals(ParticipantType.S))
                             .thenComparing(PRDto::getName))
            .collect(toList());
```

Comment: @Holger The primary comparator compares by name if only both elements to compare are of type `S`. I should have retuned `0` to be consistent with the naming

Comment: @Holger No it is'nt. Imagine having two objects in the list `PRDto("z", ParticipantType.F), PRDto("e", ParticipantType.D_F)` In terms of type they are considerd equal and if I don't sort them by name afterwards the list will remain the same.

Comment: @Holger Many thanks for the hints. I was fixated on my approach and had not understood at first what you were pointing out. I get it now.

Comment: It still does't work as expected, I want a list on the top of which are the elements with type "S" and after that all other elements sorted alphabetically

Comment: @n1cula you have to insert a `!` (logical not), depending on whether `S` should be first or last.

Answer (score 4):

Note that if you want to sort by type first and then by name you need to do so. Doing it the other way round would require the sort algorithm to keep the existing order for equal elements which might not always be guaranteed.

It would also be easier to map the enum to an integer representing the order and let `Comparator` do the work.

So your code could look like this:

```
...
.sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(p -> { //first compare by mapped type
     switch( p.getParticipantType() ) {
       case S: return 0;
       default: return Integer.MAX_VALUE; //so you could insert other enum values if needed
     }
   }).thenComparing(PRDto::getName) //then compare by name
)
...
```

If you use a composite comparator like this it will put elements with type `S` at the top. If you'd write that comparator the "old" way it could look like this:

```
compare(PRDto left, PRDto right) {
  int typeOrderLeft = mapToInt(left.getParticipantType()); //mapToInt contains the mapping expression, i.e the switch in the example above
  int typeOrderRight = mapToInt(right.getParticipantType());
  
  //first order by type
  int result = Integer.compare(typeOrderLeft, typeOrderRight);

  //if the type order is the same, i.e. both have S or non-S, sort by name
  if( result == 0 ) { 
    result = String.compare(left.getName(), right.getName());
  }

  return result; 
}
```

Example (already ordered):

```
type  name
---------------
S     zulu      //S < F and S < D_F due to the mapping, name is irrelevant here
D_F   alpha     //F and D_F are considered equal, so names are compared
F     bravo
```